# Mongoose nested schema validation not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose

I have the following Mongoose models:

```
RequestSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  merchant: 
     type: String
     required: true
  products: [ 'Product' ]
)
Request = mongoose.model('Request', RequestSchema)

ProductSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  _type: String 
  product_id:
    type: String
    required: true
  quantity:
    type: String
    required: true

)
Product = mongoose.model('Product', ProductSchema)
```

However, when I pass in the following request (which is missing a quantity), it gets validated and saved to the database:

```
{"merchant": "ABC", "products":[{"product_id":"12345"}]}
```

However, when I try leaving out the merchant, it gives a schema validation error attempting to save it:

```
{"products":[{"product_id":"12345", "quantity": "1"}]}
```

How do I make it so that these both return validation errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to refer to the schema object when you want to use subdocuments and have them validated:

```
ProductSchema = mongoose.Schema(...)

RequestSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  merchant: 
    type: String
    required: true
  products: [ ProductSchema ]
)
```

This will give a validation error on the first document:

```
ValidationError: Path `quantity` is required.
```